# Saving the value of req.query['name'] to a variable in Node.jS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am coding a login system in node.js, I am trying to do this:

```
var auth = req.query['name']
```

to which I would then compare auth with the result from the database query, but when ever  I try and load the page with /?name=foo I get this error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

my current code is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello! every thing is working!');
    var auth = req.query['name']
    if (auth === "ozzie"){// I will obviously change this.
        res.send('Hello! Your details have been authenticated')
    }
    else
    {
        res.send('Sorry! That did not work! please try again! ')
    }
});


app.listen(8888, '127.0.0.1'); 
console.log('running on, local Ip + 8888');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're attempting to send two responses to the same request, the first time with

```
res.send('hello! every thing is working!');
```

and the second time is inside the `if` or `else` block. Remove the first one and it should work fine or concatenate the output and have just one `res.send()` that is passed the concatenated output.

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense, how can I print text to the browser when visiting the page like res.send would do?

Comment: Ignore that last comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a response at the beginning of your callback:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.send('hello! every thing is working!'); // here
```

Then, calling the same thing in a conditional `if - else` block once more.
Since calling the `send()` method sets headers, you end up doing the same twice.

Remove the first one and you'll be OK.

**Note:** For debugging purposes you could resort to using `console.log` and view the debug info on the console where you ran your application's main file.